# Error: Too Few Subscripts for Specified for Array

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90

I have the following code trying to read in temperature values from a binary file. I believe it to be two dimensional but I'm not sure. And I don't know the exact dimensions. The error I'm getting says: too few subscripts specified for the array 'temp'.

```
INTEGER :: i, j
REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: temp

OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE='Orbital_TB_bufr_v620.dat', IOSTAT=iostat)
READ(unit=8,REC =1, IOSTAT=iostat) temp

ALLOCATE (temp(i:j))
print *, temp

CLOSE(8)
```

I just want to read in all the values from the file.

Comment: Your IO will not work like that, but the error you get is from the allocate statement. You define temp to be 2 dimensional but allocate it as one-dimensional. To allocate a two-dimensional array you would need to do something like `allocate(temp(i,j))`.

Comment: Check how you allocate your array, you need to supply two extends because you have a 2D array, you are supplying a range. Your range is based on non initialized variables `i` and `j`. You should allocate your array before you use it in a read statement, not after you read. For the reading, you should have an idea of how your data were written to file before trying to read it. First catch is that you do not open the file as a direct access file, and you are trying to read it as direct access file. You need to supply the `recl` while opening in order to read it as direct access.

Comment: Do you have access to a modern compiler (2008+)? If so, please use the `newunit` specifier instead of hard-coding file unit identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALLOCATE (temp(i:j))` allocates a 1D array with lower bound `i` and upper bound `j`.

However, `temp` is declared as a 2D array `DIMENSION(:,:)`.

You must make it consistent.